# ColdFusion bug - cfinput mask doesn't work with cfmail

Tags: coldfusion, mask, cfmail, cfinput

Using a mask on a cfinput field causes the email to not go through. I remove the mask and the email is sent fine.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<cfform method="post" action="submit2.cfm" name="theform">
<cfinput type="text" name="SSN" size="30" mask="999-99-9999">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</cfform>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and

```
<CFMAIL 
TO="me@example.com"
FROM="me@example.com"
SUBJECT="?">  
<cfoutput>
#Form.SSN# 
</cfoutput>
</CFMAIL>
```

Comment: Works fine for me on CF9. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using CF8. Or could there be an email configuration problem, I wonder?

Comment: dump the form scope out and abort the page processing before the email is sent. See what, if any, differences there are in the passed values. I cannot see anything that looks wrong there but that's the easiest way to make sure the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @Jon Wilson - `#Form.SSN#` You are not really emailing social security numbers .. right?

Comment: @Rob Barthle - Thanks for the suggestion. I added <cfdump var="#Form#"><cfabort> to the page but all looks normal.

Comment: @Leigh - Excellent question. No, the original mask was a different type of code, but I thought this example would be clearer.

Comment: @Jon Wilson - Phew.. I was scared for a minute ;) I do not see an obvious reason it would not work. But did you check the undelivr mail folder to see if the message is there? If it is your server, could also enable debugging. See debug="true" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html

Answer (score -1):

it works for me as is(CF9), but since your are on CF8 try adding the cfmail type.

```
<CFMAIL 
 TO="123@xyz.com"
 FROM="xyzn@123.com"
 SUBJECT="?"
 type="html">
    <cfoutput>
       #Form.SSN# 
    </cfoutput>
</CFMAIL>
```